# Unkown error message when trying to install Haskell Platform on Windows

Tags: haskell, chocolatey, haskell-platform

When trying to install the Haskell Platform via Chocolatey as outlined in the default instructions at haskell.org/platform, I get an error when trying to install the cabal and ghc packages.

```
**cabal message:**
Attempt to get headers for https://downloads.haskell.org/cabal/cabal-install-3.4.0.0/cabal-install-3.4.0.0-x86_64-windows.zip failed.
  The remote file either doesn't exist, is unauthorized, or is forbidden for url 'https://downloads.haskell.org/cabal/cabal-install-3.4.0.0/cabal-install-3.4.0.0-x86_64-windows.zip'. Exception calling "GetResponse" with "0" argument(s): "The operation has timed out"
Downloading cabal 64 bit
  from 'https://downloads.haskell.org/cabal/cabal-install-3.4.0.0/cabal-install-3.4.0.0-x86_64-windows.zip'
ERROR: The remote file either doesn't exist, is unauthorized, or is forbidden for url 'https://downloads.haskell.org/cabal/cabal-install-3.4.0.0/cabal-install-3.4.0.0-x86_64-windows.zip'. Exception calling "GetResponse" with "0" argument(s): "The operation has timed out"
The install of cabal was NOT successful.
Error while running 'C:\ProgramData\chocolatey\lib\cabal\tools\chocolateyInstall.ps1'.
 See log for details.
```

```
**ghc messages:**
Attempt to get headers for https://downloads.haskell.org/~ghc/9.0.1/ghc-9.0.1-x86_64-unknown-mingw32.tar.xz failed.
  The remote file either doesn't exist, is unauthorized, or is forbidden for url 'https://downloads.haskell.org/~ghc/9.0.1/ghc-9.0.1-x86_64-unknown-mingw32.tar.xz'. Exception calling "GetResponse" with "0" argument(s): "The operation has timed out"
Downloading ghc 64 bit
  from 'https://downloads.haskell.org/~ghc/9.0.1/ghc-9.0.1-x86_64-unknown-mingw32.tar.xz'
ERROR: The remote file either doesn't exist, is unauthorized, or is forbidden for url 'https://downloads.haskell.org/~ghc/9.0.1/ghc-9.0.1-x86_64-unknown-mingw32.tar.xz'. Exception calling "GetResponse" with "0" argument(s): "The operation has timed out"
The install of ghc was NOT successful.
Error while running 'C:\ProgramData\chocolatey\lib\ghc\tools\chocolateyInstall.ps1'.
 See log for details.
```

Any help greatly appr

Comment: for me the downloads seem to work right now - maybe it was an down when you tried? Can you retry? If not maybe you should have a look at your network (maybe your network/administrators are blocking zip/tar files or the domain?)

Comment: Put `https://downloads.haskell.org/cabal/cabal-install-3.4.0.0/cabal-install-3.4.0.0-x86_64-windows.zip` into your browser. Do you get a zip download, or an error? If you get an error, the problem is with your network, not cabal/GHC.

Comment: @AriFordsham I get a zip download when I enter that link.

Comment: @Carsten I get the same error upon retrying today. How would I check if my network is blocking zip/tar files? I'm just using my home pc/network

Comment: Do you have a proxy in your network? If you can download the file in the browser it does indicate that it's not your network but sometimes a proxy/firewall needs authentication. You could try to download it with curl for example to check if it works from a console - if so I'd open an issue on the stack-github

Comment: PS: could be a anti-virus solution blocking the downloaded file too ...